# database connection using c3p0

Tags: java, spring, c3p0

Currently in my project the datasource , transactionmanager and other bean required for database connectivity are defined in xml file and there values are configured in property file from which it takes to do the connection.
for ex:

```xml
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${DRIVER_CLASS}" p:jdbcUrl="${DB_URL}"
    p:minPoolSize="${MIN_DB_POOL_SIZE}" p:maxPoolSize="${DB_POOL_SIZE}"
    p:maxStatements="${DB_POOL_SIZE}" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="${IDLE_CONNECTION_TEST_PERIOD}"
    p:loginTeimeout="${LOGIN_TIMEOUT}" scope="singleton"></bean>
```

ALL these like values ${DB_POOL_SIZE} are configured in property file. 
the class `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` is final class and can't be extended. so my requirement is
:when spring create the bean of Datasource i should be able to set the value of the variable in xml(DB_URL) from my java file through setter method.
how to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get what you are trying to do, but if your problem is that you'd like to extend `ComboPoolDataSource` with some custom functionality, just extend `AbstractComboPooledDataSource`. Check out the source to [ComboPooledDataSource](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/master/src/java/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.java). There's not much there (once you get past the annoying copyright header). Use that as a template, and extend `AbstractComboPooledDataSource` however you'd like.